# How to develop P2P chat web application

Tags: asp.net, sockets, udp, chat, p2p

I am working on asp.net web based peer to peer chat application. I am using UDP sockets for communication. As my application is P2P I should avoid interactions with server and let peers to send and receive their messages.

Now my doubt is where am I suppose to write socket related coding? If i write socket related coding in controller classes, the coding comes under server side right? Every time user sends a message from browser it will call my controller class where my sockets were defined, and will send messages to the remote peer. Does this kind of socket programming (sockets defined in controller classes) will result in peer to peer application?

Comment: I don't get it. You're running asp.net on the clients?
I thought asp.net was supposed to be used on servers...

Keep in mind that true P2P means that there is no server involved in interactions between the peers.

Comment: So what kind of .net frame work i suppose to choose for building p2p

Comment: You clearly aren't aware of what the .net framework *is*.

Comment: Can you outline why specifically you want your application to be P2P? Is it just to reduce load on a central server? Be as detailed as you can - this question is too vague presently to give a solid answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Peer to peer communications, you do not pass any data via your server, but let the clients communicate to each other directly.

In web applications, true P2P is near impossible to achieve.
You could try to achieve something not-entirely-unlike peer-to-peer communication with javascript and HTML5 websockets on the clients.

In this scenario, you would use your asp.net server as a broker to set up the connections between your clients. 
(since your server knows where to reach your clients).
Your javascript clients should from that moment on handle the rest of the communication business.